# Janus invalid session (null)

Tags: websocket, janus, janus-gateway

I've just set up janus and got it running.

I'm connecting to it, and can see in the janus logs:

`[ERR] [transports/janus_http.c:janus_http_handler:1522] Invalid session (null)`

I've looked online but can't find anything. Any ideas?

Comment: ditched janus for a cloud service - eg Twilio - instead. IMO janus is not worth the hassle, and their dev community is detrimental to one's wellbeing. Avoid!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ditched janus for a cloud service - eg Twilio - instead. IMO janus is not worth the hassle, and their dev community is detrimental to one's wellbeing. Avoid! – bionara just now   Edit   Delete

Comment: Have to agree. Asked them where I could find stuff in the docs to get started. "You need to read the docs". Useless numpty.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anyone has the same question.
I got this error when I clicked the "start" button on janus demo page(videoroom.html) and an alert showed up something like "is the server down?".

I compared the janus demo's js script with the official testing website, I found they had replaced the HTTPS URL with wss. I uploaded a screenshot of the replaced part. Change it and everything works fine for me.

Ref:https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/docs/deploy.html
[official one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8oVA.png)